# VS Code Terminal directory path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to find a way to get rid of the c:\directory showing every time i execute a line of code.

Also, execute command CLS to clear before running again, basically clear the previous run, once i click run button.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eddXF.png)

Comment: You can probably call something like Console.Clear(); from python or something. As for the 'C:\...' part - that is the path to the executable that you're running (python.exe) so that is not something you can hide.

Comment: you probably have not searched first for an answer, you are number 101 who is asking this

Comment: "you probably have not searched first for an answer"  Believe me i did, and i did it thoroughly.

Thank you for your feedback1

Comment: Just found this on how to clear the Terminal to clear prior run

import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()

Worked well for me at my end.

Comment: Also this one works to clear the terminal, add prior to the code

import os
os.system('cls')